# Youtube API v3 - get duration

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

By using Youtube API v3, I am getting duarion in below formation.

```
PT3H32M50S
```

I want to transform this into 03:32:50 format.

**Please Note:** if video is not hour long then, I will get PT32M50S. In this case, I should get 00:32:50.

Please guide me to the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` really simple and easy solution. **[DEMO](http://viper-7.com/goHoOs)**

```
echo str_ireplace(array('PT', 'H', 'M', 'S'), array('0',':',':',''), 'PT3H32M50S');
```

Comment: Final output comes like "3:32:50". I want it like "03:32:50"

Answer (score 0):

Try This... [Demo Here](http://viper-7.com/0VRhmM)

```
<?php
$duration_youtube='PT3H32M50S';
if (strpos($duration_youtube,'H') !== false)
{
    $duration_youtube_temp = $duration_youtube;
    preg_match('~PT(.*?)H~', $duration_youtube_temp, $duration_youtube_temp_out);

    $duration_youtube_temp_out_pad=str_pad($duration_youtube_temp_out[1], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $duration_youtube=preg_replace("/".$duration_youtube_temp_out[1]."/",$duration_youtube_temp_out_pad,$duration_youtube,1);

    $duration_youtube=str_replace('PT','',$duration_youtube);
    $duration_youtube=str_replace('H',':',$duration_youtube);
    $duration_youtube=str_replace('M',':',$duration_youtube);
    $duration_youtube=str_replace('S','',$duration_youtube);
}
else
{
    $duration_youtube=str_replace('PT','00:',$duration_youtube);
    $duration_youtube=str_replace('M',':',$duration_youtube);
    $duration_youtube=str_replace('S','',$duration_youtube);
}
echo $duration_youtube;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function youtubeTime($yStr){
    $s=$m=$h='00';
    preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$yStr,$parts);
    if(!empty($parts)){
        $ts=array_pop($parts[0]);
        $s = ($ts<10)? '0'.(int)$ts : $ts;
        $ms=array_pop($parts[0]);
        $m = ($ms<10)? '0'.(int)$ms : $ms;
        $hs=array_pop($parts[0]);
        $h = ($hs<10)? '0'.(int)$hs : $hs;
    }
    return $h.':'.$m.':'.$s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got below solution which works in my all possible scenarios.

```
$duration = str_ireplace(array('PT', 'H', 'M', 'S'), array('',':',':',''),         
$youtubeArrData->items[0]->contentDetails->duration);
if(substr_count($duration, ':') == 0){
    $duration = "00:00:".$duration;
}
if(substr_count($duration, ':') == 1){
    $duration = "00:".$duration;
}
$video_Length = date("H:i:s.u", strtotime($duration));
```

Hope this works for everybody.